# Counter with "for" displaying on a dynamic textfield

Tags: actionscript-3, for-loop, counter, dynamic-text

im very new to as3 so i would appreciate any help.
Im trying to make a counter only using the command "for".
im counting on this from 1 to 1000 in steps of 20. 
the next step i want to make is to display on the output tab
i already know i can make it with "trace();", but i also want this to be displayed on
the main .swf window, im trying using a dynamic text-field which i named "dyna"

**The problem is that, it is only displaying the last number. "1000" or changing very fast that i barely notice, and the last one remains.**

```
var i:int;
for (i = 1; i < 1001; i+=20)
{
trace(i);
//dyna is the name of my dynamic textfiled
dyna.text = i.toString();
//dinamico.text = String(i);
}
```

-Is there any way to record all the numbers on my dynamic textbox, something like [1,20,40,60,....] horizontally or vertically.

-Or maybe someway to  run this from a button step by step.
like [click, 20; click, 40; click 60.....]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
var i:int;
var str:String="1";

for (i = 20; i < 1001; i+=20)
{
  str=str+","+i;
}
dyna.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
dyna.text=str;
```

Output
1,20,40,60,80,100,120,140,160...

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks. it worked! just now the output is too long. so i think im gonna make it step by step with a button.

Answer (score 0):

To run this from the button step by step you need a button, a listener attached to the button, a counter available to both button and text field, and a bit of code. The button has to be somewhere on the stage or in your asset, and named somehow, so you can address it by the name. Here it's named `yourButton`:

```
var counter:int=0;
yourButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,updateDyna);
function updateDyna(e:MouseEvent):void {
    counter+=20;
    if (counter>1000) counter=1000;
    dyna.text=counter.toString();
}
```

Here you are, click - 20, click - 40, etc., up to 1000.

Comment: nice thanks, it helped me a lot. it worked nice, im just trying to run this method from a "for" form

    for (i = 1; i < 1001; i+=20)

Comment: Count a call to click listener as a single iteration of your cycle, all preparations as what you are writing in brackets within `for(...)` construction. Also, your "for" cycle will not stop to display you the previous value of the counter, so either use this, or use `dyna.appendText()` to concatenate old text with anything new.